# The bufferArray isn't completely sent to the server i received byteLength 20 instead of 40366

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch, buffer

- Hello Everyone
- I have an issues that i can't figure out why this happened
- On the client side i have an audio bufferArray that uses some function for normalize and slice operation then return a wav audioBuffer
- while check the returned bufferArray in the browser console the `byteLength` is `40366` but when using `fetch` api to send this arrayBuffer to the server i always getting the bufferArray `byteLength` as `20` i don't know why it's not sended to the server can anyone help me
- Here's my code
- on Client Side

```js
(async() => {
//fetch an api and take the arrayBuffer
let data = await fetch(url);
let buff = await data.arrayBuffer();
//Normalize and Slice and return arrayBuffer wav 
let audioBuffer = normalizeAndSlice(buff);
//sending the buffer to the server
let fd = new FormData();
fd.append("buffer", audioBuffer)
await fetch(url, {
   method: "POST",
   body: fd,
}).then(res => res.json())
.then(json => console.log(json);
//Check the buffer
//Here's byteLength 40366
console.log(audioBuffer)
//Create Blob
console.log(new Blob([audioBuffer], {type: "audio/wav"});
})()
```

- On Server Side

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer();
const data = upload.fields([{name: "buffer", maxCount: 1}]);
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.post("/", data, function (req, res) {
  const {buffer: buff} = req.body
  //Here's the byteLength is 20
  console.log(buff.byteLength)
});
```

> Tip: i don't want to upload the file it's can easily uploaded while sending the blob from the client side instead of buffer i want just the audioBuffer to use it in another operation and sending the result to the clent again